# Create Project from Published App

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2013

I've got a serious problem at this moment.

About 6 months ago, I had a C# Project on my laptop which I was working on. I published this App on a server, and it was running fine. In the meantime, we've switched to new laptops, and the old one is wiped. 
But in the meantime, we found a bug in the application that I published.
I tried getting back the code but only got the old code which is not up-to-date...

Is it possible that I create a project from a published web app?
Because then I will have the latest version of all the code back.

-Mitch

Comment: Did you search for reverse engineering options?

Comment: Side note, please take this as a kick in the backside to consider and evaluate version control systems. Especially for code that will end up being of value to your company :)

Comment: On the plus side, maybe you now get to rewrite it w/o silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

There are various decompilation tools out there, where you basically feed in a dll and get back a relatively okay version of your code. Do keep in mind that it will not be like for like. Your original code base is gone, for all intents and purposes.

One such tool is https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/. It's a free tool but I've used it in the past to crack open binaries.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try :)